# Select all items before hovered item

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a container with 5 inline stars.

What I need is when you hover over a star, that star and all the stars before it get a different background . (I'm using a sprite so I change the background position for this)

Markup:

```
<div class="wpr"> 
    <span class="star"></span>
    <span class="star"></span>
    <span class="star"></span>
    <span class="star"></span>
    <span class="star"></span>
</div>
```

If I use the sibling combinator (~) I get the reverse effect.

```
.star:hover, .star:hover ~ .star
{
    background-position: 0 -18px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/p8MKt/2/)

How can I implement this for the all the stars before the hovered one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who feels that `direction: rtl` is too hacky (because it was never really designed to align a group of star rating icons), I recommend [floating the stars to the right](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/p8MKt/5) instead:

```
.star {
    float: right;
    width: 20px;
    height: 15px;
    background: url(stars.png) 0 -1px no-repeat;
}
```

Since the wrapper is an inline block itself anyway, it will still shrink-to-fit.

For that matter, you can even [float the wrapper as well](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/p8MKt/6) if you decide that you *really* hate inline blocks and want to ditch them entirely:

```
.wpr {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: Although my solution also works fine for what I need, this solution does feel like the correct way it should be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Lol, just figured it out,

I just need to add `direction: rtl;` on the wrapper.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/p8MKt/3/)**

Comment: Normally, you can't select elements that are before the hovered item. This is an awesome solution!! Probably won't work in all cases, but for this specific case, its great!

Comment: Specifically, the reason why this works is because your `.star` elements are all inline blocks, and all you're doing is changing the direction of those inlines. Of course, the moment you add any text to the content of the wrapper, that text will get reversed, causing this solution to fall flat.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the other (good) answers - you could also use `transform:rotate()`.

Rotate the parent element -180 degrees:

```
.wpr {
    transform:rotate(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);
}
```

Then rotate the children elements 180 degrees:

```
.star {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

[**WORKING EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M8Jrz/)

Just be aware of the support of [CSS3 transforms](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d).

If this is a concern, you can throw in the `-ms`/`-moz`/`-o` vendors prefixes too.