# Change star rating on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use this code to display stars:

```
<ul class="rating">
<li>
<span class="ratingSelector">
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-1-5" value="1" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-1-5"></label>
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-2-5" value="2" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-2-5"></label>
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-3-5" value="3" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-3-5"></label>
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-4-5" value="4" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-4-5"></label>
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-5-5" value="5" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-5-5"></label>
</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Dynamic code:

```
         <ul class="rating">
            <?php foreach ($this->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
                <li>
                    <span class="rowlabel"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></span>
                    <span class="ratingSelector">
                <?php foreach ($_rating->getOptions() as $_option): ?>
                    <input type="radio" name="ratings[<?php echo $_rating->getId() ?>]" id="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>-<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>-5" value="<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" class="radio" /><label class="full" for="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>-<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>-5"></label>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </span>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```

But hovering and selecting currently works from right to left, but I want to change this from left to right.

**Code is loaded dynamically, so I can not change the sort and put value 5 first. This dynamic code is loaded 5 times, for 5 different ratings.**

How can I change this?
Or what code of JQuery do I need?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9nn14beq/

Comment: I don't think this is possible with only css. because css rule is applied for next sibling not for previous. You should also use JQuery.

Comment: See my star rating system in CSS - http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/qvhtf

Comment: @vsync What exactly are you doing different than my code?

Comment: @Jelle - well I saw you are trying to make a star rating system and since I wrote a good one some years ago, I thought it would be nice to share it, so you could use it. Read the source code and learn how it was done

Comment: @ketan Yes, it is posible with CSS only. See my answer

Comment: @vals not exactly, because how to set the value, when selecting? So to show the color when clicking?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226125/select-all-items-before-hovered-item

Comment: @Danield nope, this question has more quirks than just hovering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can *almost* work with pure CSS. It does need one line of JavaScript to set the initial value though:

```js
document.getElementById('Degelijkheid-1-5').checked = true;
```

```css
.rating input {
    display: none;
}
.rating label:before {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    content:"\f005";
}
li {
    list-style:none;
}

.ratingSelector input + label {
    color: #FFD700;
}
.ratingSelector input:checked ~ input:not(:checked) ~ label {
    color: #ddd;
}
.ratingSelector input:checked ~ input:not(:checked) + label:hover ~ label {
    color: #ddd;
}
.ratingSelector:hover input + label,
.ratingSelector:hover input:checked + label {
    color: #FFED85;
}
.ratingSelector:hover input:checked ~ input:not(:checked) ~ label:hover,
.ratingSelector:hover input:checked ~ input:not(:checked) + label {
    color: #FFD700;
}
.ratingSelector:hover input:checked ~ input:not(:checked) ~ label:hover ~ label {
    color: #ddd !important;
}
.ratingSelector input + label:hover ~ label {
    color: #ddd !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="rating">
    <li> <span class="ratingSelector">
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-1-5" value="1" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-1-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-2-5" value="2" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-2-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-3-5" value="3" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-3-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-4-5" value="4" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-4-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-5-5" value="5" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-5-5"></label>
    </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### EDIT

To use JS (to re-order the items):

```js
var objGroup = document.getElementsByClassName('ratingSelector');
for (var i = 0; i < objGroup.length; i++) {
  var objRadio = [].slice.call(objGroup[i].getElementsByClassName('full')); // Create an array of items
  for (var j = objRadio.length; j--;) { // Loop through the array backwards
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(objRadio[j].getAttribute('for'));
    objGroup[i].appendChild(checkbox);
    objGroup[i].appendChild(objRadio[j]);
  }
}
```

```css
.rating {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: left;
}
.rating input {
  display: none;
}
.rating label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.rating label {
  color: #ddd;
}
/***** CSS to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.ratingSelector input:checked ~ label,
/* show gold star when clicked */

.ratingSelector label:hover,
/* hover current star */

.ratingSelector label:hover ~ label {
  color: #FFD700;
}
/* hover previous stars in list */

.ratingSelector input:checked + label:hover,
/* hover current star when changing rating */

.ratingSelector input:checked ~ label:hover,
.ratingSelector label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label,
/* lighten current selection */

.ratingSelector input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<ul class="rating">
  <li> <span class="ratingSelector">
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-1-5" value="1" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-1-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-2-5" value="2" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-2-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-3-5" value="3" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-3-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-4-5" value="4" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-4-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-5-5" value="5" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-5-5"></label>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li> <span class="ratingSelector">
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-1-5" value="1" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Design-1-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-2-5" value="2" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Design-2-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-3-5" value="3" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Design-3-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-4-5" value="4" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Design-4-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[2]" id="Design-5-5" value="5" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Design-5-5"></label>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li> <span class="ratingSelector">
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[3]" id="Gebruiksgemak-1-5" value="1" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Gebruiksgemak-1-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[3]" id="Gebruiksgemak-2-5" value="2" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Gebruiksgemak-2-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[3]" id="Gebruiksgemak-3-5" value="3" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Gebruiksgemak-3-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[3]" id="Gebruiksgemak-4-5" value="4" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Gebruiksgemak-4-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ratings[3]" id="Gebruiksgemak-5-5" value="5" class="radio"/>
<label class="full" for="Gebruiksgemak-5-5"></label>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Almost awesome. But the element ID like "Degelijkheid" is also loaded dynamically. I'll updated my question with the dynamic code also. Because this only works for 1 line.

Comment: @Jelle if the class name is always "radio" and that class isn't being used elsewhere, you could use: `document.getElementsByClassName('radio')[0].checked = true;` instead

Comment: the only problem is that my code is loaded 5 times. See this JSFiddle for the new problem. https://jsfiddle.net/pc6z09x9/1/

Comment: @Jelle I've added an edit that should fix _part_ of the problem, however your inputs all share the same name so you'll need to fix that (each group of 5 need the same name).

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) It is not possible to not select any star? Because now star 1 is always selected.

Comment: @Jelle Here's those fixes working: https://jsfiddle.net/pc6z09x9/2/. No it's not possible, unless you re-write the whole thing to use JS instead of CSS...

Comment: thanks!! Is it hard to right entire JS to fix that? Because I really do not know how to fix this with JS.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I found the problem. The last line in your javascript does change the value of the field. But the "input id" and "label for" are also loaded dynamic but these do not change. So the form is not working anymore.

Comment: Jamie is it also possible to display text inside the label on hover? So when you hover star 1 it display something like "Bad" and when you hover star 5 it display something like "Amazing"? And that also for all other values.

Comment: @Jelle Yes it would, you'd either need to amend the HTML or hard-code something in JS. If you're wanting to show a little caption though, I would show it at end of the `LI` because your labels are currently holding your stars.

Answer (score 0):

You expected thing is possible with only css. Because css rule is applied for next sibling not for previous. You should also use JQuery.

But you can do it using following trick using css:

```css
.rating input { display: none; } 
.rating label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

li {list-style:none;
direction:rtl;
text-align: left;}

.rating label { 
  color: #ddd;
}

/***** CSS to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

```html
<ul class="rating">
<li>
<span class="ratingSelector">
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-5-5" value="5" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-5-5"></label>
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-4-5" value="4" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-4-5"></label>
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-3-5" value="3" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-3-5"></label>
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-2-5" value="2" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-2-5"></label>
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-1-5" value="1" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-1-5"></label>
</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is that the code is loaded dynamically. So I can't change the order and set value 5 first. Is there a way to get it done loaded value 1 first?

Comment: @Jelle For that you should use JQuery as i mention in my question.

Comment: And what does that code looks like, because I do not know how to manage this with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in previous answers, CSS selectors work only in the netural order of the DOM. (Even though this can change some time in the future).

So, if you can not change your DOM, you need to reverse your CSS logic:

Change all the elements on hover of the container. And then use the sibling selector to change the elements to the right of the hovered item

```css
.rating input { display: none; } 
.rating label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

li {list-style:none; }

/***** CSS to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating label {color: grey;}
label:hover { color: red;  }
.ratingSelector:hover .full {color: red; }
.full:hover ~ .full { color: grey !important;  }
```

```html
<ul class="rating">
<li>
<span class="ratingSelector">
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-1-5" value="1" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-1-5"></label>
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-2-5" value="2" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-2-5"></label>
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-3-5" value="3" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-3-5"></label>
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-4-5" value="4" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-4-5"></label>
<input type="radio" name="ratings[1]" id="Degelijkheid-5-5" value="5" class="radio">
<label class="full" for="Degelijkheid-5-5"></label>
</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but when selecting a star (or intact a input radio), it needs to keep the color, to indicate the review value. So how can I manage that?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below CSS code to make it from left to right:

```
.ratingSelector {
    max-width: 145px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.rating label {
    float: right;
}
```