# Jquery Star rating issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

need some help on a star rating system i am working on. The issue is that i have multiple star rating on a single page but if i click on a star for another field, it will highlight all the previous unlighted stars too. Not sure how to fix it, please help. Below are my codes.

```css
        function highlightStar(obj) {
            removeHighlight();      
            $('li').each(function(index) {
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
                if(index == $("li").index(obj)) {
                    return false;   
                }
            });
        }
        function removeHighlight() {
            $('li').removeClass('selected');
            $('li').removeClass('highlight');
        }
        function addRating(obj) {
            $('li').each(function(index) {
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                $('#rating').val((index+1));
                if(index == $("li").index(obj)) {
                    return false;   
                }
            });
        }
        function resetRating() {
            if($("#rating").val()) {
                $('li').each(function(index) {
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                    if((index+1) == $("#rating").val()) {
                        return false;   
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="db-table1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" border="1">    
             <tr>
                <td>Field 1</td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="rating" id="rating" />
            <ul onMouseOut="resetRating();">
              <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
              <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
              <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
              <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
              <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Field 2</td>
            <td>  
            <input type="text" name="rating2" id="rating2" />        
            <ul onMouseOut="resetRating();">
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Field 3</td>
            <td>   
            <input type="text" name="rating3" id="rating3" />    
            <ul onMouseOut="resetRating();">
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
            </tr>     
            <tr>
                <td>Field 4</td>
            <td>    
            <input type="text" name="rating4" id="rating4" />    
            <ul onMouseOut="resetRating();">
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
                <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">?</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
            </tr>   </table>
```

Comment: because you are selecting all of the lis on the page, not the ones in the current collection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can i ask how do i select just the ones in the current collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of all those inline functions, just create some listeners:

```
$('li').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight'); // Add it to the clicked on LI
    $(this).prevAll('li').addClass('highlight'); // Add to all previous LI siblings too
});

$('li').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('li').removeClass('highlight');
});

$('li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).prevAll('li').addClass('selected');
});
```

Then all the HTML you need is:

```
<ul>
    <li>?</li>
    <li>?</li>
    <li>?</li>
    <li>?</li>
    <li>?</li>
</ul>
```

Or even better JS code than above:

```
$('li').hover(function() { // Mouse In
    $(this).addClass('highlight'); // Add it to the clicked on LI
    $(this).prevAll('li').addClass('highlight'); // Add to all previous LI siblings too
},function() { // Mouse Out
    $('li').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Or, as crush quite rightly pointed out, use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$('table.db-table1').on('mouseenter', 'li', function( event ) {        
    $(this).addClass('highlight'); // Add it to the clicked on LI
    $(this).prevAll('li').addClass('highlight'); // Add to all previous LI 
}).on('mouseleave', 'li', function( event ) {
    $('li').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

This will add two listeners, instead of many more.

Comment: Might as well go the next step and use event delegation

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So do you mean that instead of using the highlightStar and removeHighlight function, it's better to use event delegation? After I tried replacing the functions with event delegation but now the stars will not light up.

Comment: Just for fun and to add a little pizazz, I updated your example to use ascii stars as oppose to question marks [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/d21m4b51/2/). Your delegation example works great though +1.

Comment: @Pete yes on purpose because more than one item gets the class added and it would be silly to run the same two calls as there are on mouseenter :)

Comment: Thanks for the example! Now i have another question, when using your example, how do i get the stars highlight to stick when i click it?

Comment: @grahf23 You could use checkboxes. Have a look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30569387/2117156)

Comment: @Jamie Barker Ok, i managed to get it to work now but can i ask how do i changed the checkbox to stars? I had tried using background: url("star.png") no-repeat center center; but it end up showing both the checkbox and the star icon. When i click it also did not highlight the star, only the checkbox.

Comment: I said checkboxes, but I meant radio buttons. Just `display:none;` the input and make sure your star is inside a label that is linked to the input. Much like my answer in the question I linked to previously. If you're still struggling, put your code in a JSFiddle and I'll have a brief look at it.

Comment: @JamieBarker Ok i managed to get it to work. Silly me forgot to link properly to the css style. Worked beautifully now. Thanks.