# How to check mouseover operation changes the UI colour in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to verify whether stars are lit up or not when I hover mouse on top of it.(Attached a Screenshot for better understanding). How can I verify whether it is lit up or not?

[image]

HTML structure of the element is as given below:

```
<span class="wh-rating rating_4_5" style="display: inline-block;">
Rating:
<span data-s13732055i-ir="this" itemprop="ratingValue">4.5</span>
</span>
<div class="wh-rating-choices" style="display: none;">
<div class="wh-rating-choices-holder">
 <a class="hover" href="#">1</a>
 <a class="hover" href="#">2</a>
 <a class="hover" href="#">3</a>
 <a class="hover" href="#">4</a>
 <a class="hover" href="#">5</a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: please share some HTML structure for your webpage. There must me some attribute value for the stars that will be changing on mouseover.

Comment: <span class="wh-rating rating_4_5" style="display: inline-block;">
Rating:
<span data-s13732055i-ir="this" itemprop="ratingValue">4.5</span>
</span>
<div class="wh-rating-choices" style="display: none;">
<div class="wh-rating-choices-holder">
<a class="hover" href="#">1</a>
<a class="hover" href="#">2</a>
<a class="hover" href="#">3</a>
<a class="hover" href="#">4</a>
<a class="hover" href="#">5</a>
<em>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this based on example DOM given below

```
<ul class="rw-ui-stars">
<li class="rw-ui-star-0 rw-ui-star-selected"></li>
<li class="rw-ui-star-1 rw-ui-star-selected"></li>
<li class="rw-ui-star-2 rw-ui-star-selected"></li>
<li class="rw-ui-star-3 rw-ui-star-selected"></li>
<li class="rw-ui-star-4"></li></ul>
```

on mouseovering the star, the class attribute changes to (here i have hoveredon 5stars)

```
<ul class="rw-ui-stars">
<li class="rw-ui-star-0 rw-ui-star-over"></li>
<li class="rw-ui-star-1 rw-ui-star-over"></li>
<li class="rw-ui-star-2 rw-ui-star-over"></li>
<li class="rw-ui-star-3 rw-ui-star-over"></li>
<li class="rw-ui-star-4 rw-ui-star-over"></li></ul>
```

As you can clearly notice that the class attribute value is changing on mouseover.

you can write following code to get this automated

```
public bool isStarsSelectedOnMouseOver(int n){
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(by.xpath("//li[@class='rw-ui-star-"+(n-1)+"'"))).build().perform();

    List<WebElement> stars = driver.findElements(by.xpath("//ul[@class='rw-ui-stars'"));

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if(!stars.get(i).getAttribute("class").contains("rw-ui-star-over"))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Again the code is for illustration and can be modified according to your need

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here , at a similar project like yours check this out it can be done with pure css : [Change star rating on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568843/change-star-rating-on-hover)